# how to set custom arrows for bootstrap year calendar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change defaul arrows for bootsrap year calendar in the header(where are dates slider), I want to set my custom arrows with svg, how can I do this?

```
$('.js-yearcalendar').calendar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.calendar .calendar-header table th.next span {
  display: block;
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/118/118740.png);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: thin black solid;
  background-size: cover;
}

.calendar .calendar-header table th.next span:before {
  display: none;
}

.calendar .calendar-header table th.prev {}

.calendar .calendar-header table th.prev span {
  display: block;
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/126/126492.png);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: thin black solid;
  background-size: cover;
}

.calendar .calendar-header table th.prev span:before {
  display: none;
}
```

Add this css after your `Bootstrap's default CSS which will override its default CSS properties.`

**Note:**  change your SVG path according to your need in background URL.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the bootstrap calender in http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com

You can do this with pure CSS.

```
.calendar table.month td.day .day-content:hover {
     background:rgba(0,0,0,.2); /* This is the transparent color showing up when hovering */
     cursor:move; /* This is set as hand by default */
}
```